# Late 70s/early UK supernatural drama with an alien sitting on a bed

Tags: story-identification, tv

I can remember a drama shown on a Sunday night, at around 9pm, which featured an alien creature sitting on the end of someone's bed. I think it was set in Victorian times. The alien was semi-transparent and looked like it was made from perspex. I think it looked like a cross between [Skizz from 2000AD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxldW.jpg) and a [Micronaut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcoBH.jpg) or [Denys Fisher Cyborg.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQ03k.jpg) I can remember a lot of people standing around the bed, trying to free the person in the bed.

It may have been an anthology show, but I haven't figured out which one.

Comment: Can you remember any plot details of this you can [edit] in?

Comment: Do you remember which channel?

Answer (score 4):

I came across your inquiry while searching for the answer to the same question. I believe it was an episode of *ITV Playhouse* called "Friends in Space," written by John Ratzenberger of *Cheers* fame. Here's a couple of links.

https://www.tvcream.co.uk/telly/tv-a-z/a-m/f-is-for/friends-in-space/

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Answering an old question is not a problem at all; all good questions deserve to be answered!  You could improve your answer by including a shot of the alien to show that it matches the description in the question.